# Cosa vuol dire "fruscola" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Don Francesco non aveva ritenuto opportuno stipulare un contratto per appropriarsi di ciò che già gli apparteneva, cioè il corpo di Concetta in totale usufrutto, la sua disponibilità, devozione, e anche qualcosa che lui prendeva per amore e invece era pietà, una compassione profonda che Concetta riservava alle **fruscole** ferite, ai pezzenti e a lui, che poi non si capiva perché, visto che era ricco, sano e forte e le dava anche da mangiare.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegarmi a che cosa si riferisce l'autrice con "fruscole" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il termine ["fruscolo"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000409.jpg) su alcuni dizionari, ma nessuna delle accezioni che ho trovato sembra avere senso nel contesto del testo. O forse sono io che non riesco a vedere quale sia l'accezione giusta. Si tratterebbe di un uso regionale del termine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ho trovato per [fruscolo](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fruscolo) la seguente definizione:

> **fruscolo** frù|sco|lo s.m. 1963; der. del lat. ferus “selvaggio” forse
>   incrociato col fr. farouche “selvaggio” con 2-olo.
>
> **RE** merid.  nella tradizione popolare calabrese e lucana , spiritello ,
>   folletto o animale selvatico , considerato come un essere dotato di
>   facoltà soprannaturali

In [questo vocabolario](http://www.pinoindini.it/f.html) indicato da @Charo si può leggere:

> **FRUSCOLO**  **FRÙSKULU**    In senso figurato = prurito, capriccio, voglia.
>   Detto anche di bambino molto vivace.

In questo [dizionario etimologico di meridionalismi dell'Università di Nizza](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/frittola.htm) indicato da @user070221 si può trovare il termine *frusculo*:

> FRUSCULO
>
> GRASSO in *Nebbie di ddraunàra* 1993: "Un frusculo di donna che, con
>   l'osso puntuto del cranio, non arrivava a un metro e venti..." (p. 64,
>   cf. 2 autres occ.).
>
> Enregistré par Piccitto II 137 *frùsculu* 1 "aspro, brusco di modi .2.
>   impulsivo .3. balzano, strambo .4. spaventoso", *frùsculu* 2 " *in malu*
>   f. individuo losco", cf. Rohlfs 263 *ferùsculu* "selvaggio,
>   intrattabile...*frùsculu* furfante, persona sospetta, uomo furbo...frugolo, fanciullo che non sta mai fermo [l. *ferusculus, dim.
>   di ferus]". Cf. GDLI VI 402 *fruscolo* 2, DEI III 1725 *frùscolo* 2 "nome
>   del folletto nell'Italia merid. (luc., calabr.): vedi 'feruscolo'...", III 1625 *ferùscolo* "dial., selvaggio, intrattabile; m. animale selvatico o rapace, frugolino; v. it. merid. *f(e)rùsculu* id., *malu
>   frùsculu* furfante, lat. **ferusculus* dim. di *ferus* selvatico..."
>
> Sic. *frusculu*, calbr. *ferùsculu* < lat. parlé **FERUSCULU(M)* < lat. *FERU(M)*.
>
> ƒ démon.

Da notare che la fonte dell'accezione di "fruscolo" come  "fanciullo che non sta mai fermo" è ‎ROHLFS G., *Nuovo Dizionario dialettale della Calabria*, Longo ed., Ravenna, 1977 [: 1990].

Da queste fonti direi che il significato che si adatta maggiormente al contesto da te citato è "bambina" o "fanciulla".

Comment: Fruscole è femminile, per cui fruscola. La mia impressione è che si riferisca a bambine povere.

Comment: @user070221: Anche su [questo forum](https://www.golden-forum.it/index.php?topic=7372.185;wap2) appare "fruscola" come bambina.

Comment: Quindi si riferisce a bambine, fanciulle ferite? Si adatta al contesto?

Comment: @abarisone: Mi sembra molto plausibile che si tratti di ragazzine o fanciulle. Anch'io penso che il fatto che sia "fruscole" al femminile e non "fruscoli" faccia poco plausibile la interpretazione come animaletti selvatici.

Comment: Ti posso chiedere, @user070221, come hai avuto questa tua impressione?

Comment: In qualsiasi caso, @user070221, ti ringrazio tantissimo per il tuo commento. Perché sembra essere quello che ha dato risposta alla mia domanda (o perlomeno la risposta più plausibile rispetto a tutte le accezioni di "fruscolo" che sono riuscita a trovare). Grazie mille per aver scritto questo commento.